# Can Data Loader run with 64-bit Java?

Tags: data-loader, java, windows7

I have uninstalled all old versions of the data loader and installed the newest one: 36.0.0

I cleaned up all Java stuff on my 64-bit Win 7 machine and there's only one version left, it's this version (output of java -version):

```
java version "1.8.0_73"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_73-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.73-b02, mixed mode)
```

My JAVA_HOME environment variable is C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_73

If I open a CMD window, the java.exe can be found.

Still, trying to execute data loader results in "This application requires a Java Runtime Environment 1.8.0 (32-bit)"

So, do I really need a 32-bit Java version next to my 64-bit Java version? Is that even possible? Do I need to set up something else? I need the 64-bit version for other apps, I cannot replace it with a 32-bit version (provided that's even possible with 64-bit Win 7).

Comment: To answer one of my questions, according to the Java download site: "If you use 32-bit and 64-bit browsers, you need to download both 32-bit and 64-bit Java." So the first action is to install the 32-bit version as well. Next question: to which version should JAVA_HOME be pointing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well that was easy (does that sound sarcastic?). I installed the 32-bit Java runtime environment, so now I have two JREs: 32-bit one in C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_73 and 64-bit one in C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_73

And I didn't even have to change JAVA_HOME to get the data loader working, it just works now. Automagically. Not even PATH was changed by the installer. java -version still reports the 64-bit version, but somehow data loader can find the 32-bit version (I guess because it was installed in its default folder).

So the answer to my question is: no.

Comment: Thanks for this, I remember getting this error when I was stressed for time and just fell back to an earlier Data Loader ..now I can fix this.

Answer (score 2):

I also found the answer to be no, but there is an alternative for those that do not wish to install a 32 bit jre system - wide, but need to use one for data loader (my use case).

I followed the instructions from this (https://stackoverflow.com/a/6571736/8148972) post, and extracted the jre to my data loader folder in a new sub directory 'Java'.

You can then write a powershell, batch or commandline script to run dataloader using this jre. I used the following line in a powershell script

```
.\Java\bin\java.exe -jar dataloader-40.0.0-uber.jar -cp com.salesforce.dataloader.process.DataLoaderRunner
```

This will use the jre you extracted to run dataloader.